# What is the difference among .cast() and List.from() and List.castFrom()

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-2

List foo -> List bar
I can use three method

```
1.List<MyClass> bar = foo.cast<MyClass>()
2.List<MyClass> bar = List.castFrom(foo)
3.List<MyClass> bar = List.from(foo)
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to the additional question ("Any practical differences (not just quoting/sharing docs) as to when one would work and the other fail would be appreciated."):

When you have a *giant* array, copying it (`List.from`) will not be a smart idea - you will spend a lot of time copying everything and it will also cost you a lot of memory. Instead, you will want to use `List.cast`, which will only return a *view* and will not copy everything from the list. That is a case when `List.cast` would work and other would fail. Indeed, not fail, but not good.

Since "[List.cast is] typically implemented as List.castFrom<E, R>(this)", the example mentioned above applies to `List.castFrom` as well.

As for when should we use `List.from` but not the other two, think about the following case: You have List `a`, and want to copy it to list `b` and make some modifications to `b`. If you only want to modify `b` but want `a` to keep the original, you should use `List.from` to copy (clone) instead of the `List.cast`.

In short: `List.cast` almost same as `List.castFrom`. They both do *not* copy anything. The `List.from` copies everything.

---

Indeed, you can also look at the source code: `static List<T> castFrom<S, T>(List<S> source) => CastList<S, T>(source);` And `CastList` is implemented as:

```
abstract class _CastListBase<S, T> extends _CastIterableBase<S, T>
    with ListMixin<T> {
  List<S> get _source;

  T operator [](int index) => _source[index] as T;

...
}

class CastList<S, T> extends _CastListBase<S, T> {
...
}
```

So, you can very clearly see that, when you do `cast` (or `castFrom`), you do not copy and create a new list, but only make a very thin wrapper. That wrapper will make a type cast whenever you use it.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like this. I'll give it a read later on

Comment: @iDecode You are welcome! Don't forget to award the bounty if you find it useful ;)

Comment: I don't think List.from's cost bigger than List.cast's . List.from don't copy every element to create a new List,that's a shallow cpy,just pointer , same as create a CastList object,latter create a Object and put pointer too.

Answer (score 3):

1. `cast<MyClass>`: Returns the *view* (Immutable List, altering order of the list won't be reflected in original list) of the List containing instances of MyClass type. Please [follow](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/cast.html).
2. `castFrom(foo)`: Adapts source (foo) to be a List. Please [follow](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/castFrom.html)
3. `from(foo)`: Creates a List from Iterable (foo) objects provided in the Argument. Please [follow](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/List.from.html)